# Is there a way to get vlookups to work from data in power query?

Tags: excel

I have been using Power Query to get data from [Baseball Reference](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/majors/2022-standard-batting.shtml). Here is an example of how Baseball Reference extracts the data. [image: Player Example]

On the right is the table output using power query.  The left, to make sure that it is just the name, uses this formula to make sure just that Sandy Leon gets pulled Because of how his name is input in baseball reference, uses this formula: `=IF(RIGHT(Player_Standard_Batting[@Name],1)="*",LEFT(C416,LEN(C416)-1),IF(RIGHT(Player_Standard_Batting[@Name],1)="#",LEFT(C416,LEN(C416)-1),Player_Standard_Batting[@Name]))`.

My python code pulls the lineups into a separate CSV file that I copy and paste the results into a different spreadsheet like this: [image: DJ LeMahieu Baseball Press]

Players get pulled from [Baseball Press](https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-07) go in the column on the right. Usually, they have a position and handedness associated with their name. Because of this, I use this formula in the far left column to get around the position and handedness: `=TRIM(LEFT(G3, FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(G3, " ", "^",2)&"^")))` When I use a vlookup referencing the cell on the left to pull data referencing the DJ LeMahieu in a different tab (from the function two paragraphs above) and it gives me the #N/A that you see in the picture.

Is there any way around this or to match the formatting to make it a viable solution.

Comment: I thought you were using python to do this (or at least thats what I you had posted previously?) Either way, can you post your code/function that you are using?

Comment: @chitown88 I was using python to scrape the data and put it into a different excel sheet.  See the better explanation listed above

Comment: Ah ok. Have you considered doing the whole process in python. Pull the lineups in python. Pull the baseball reference data. Do all your joining/merging, then wrote to file. Elements excel being used as the middle man and no need to copy/paste either.